# C++ incrementing in a recursive function

Tags: c++, console-application

I found this code snippet with grepper and when looking for recursive function samples. I understand the refursive part, how the function calls itself - 1 untill it reaches the base case, however, I don't understand the last line in the else. Just trying to wrap my head around how the last line gets the number to go back up untill it's back to the starting value. Nothing in the code is setting it to +1, also, as it goes back up is it calling the function itself or is it just a rule I don't know of? Just trying to wrap my head around the logic here.

```
void PrintTest(int test)
{
    if (test < 1)
    {
        return; // Exit condition, known as "base case"
    }
    else
    {
        cout << test << " ";
        PrintTest(test-1);
        cout << test << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number prefarably between 2 and 9: ";
    cin >> a;
    PrintTest(a);
```

I know it may be a stupid question tho but just trying to understand why that "cout << test << " ";" increments the number back up that's all.

Comment: hint: `test` is never incremented or modified in any way

Comment: Each invocation of `PrintTest` has its own variable `test`.

Comment: to have a better understanding add 4 spaces margin each time you enter in `PrintTest` function. You can also add a cout in first line and in last line to trace when you enter and when you leave `PrintTest` function.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't "increment the number back up".

After the recursive step, the processing continues where it left off. So you're just seeing the "lower" stack frames complete their processing.

Here's the sequence of events, from top to bottom:

```
PrintTest(3)        PrintTest(2)         PrintTest(1)         PrintTest(0)
===============================================================================
cout << 3 << " ";
PrintTest(3-1);     cout << 2 << " ";
                    PrintTest(2-1);      cout << 1 << " ";
                                         PrintTest(1-1);      return;
                                         cout << 1 << " ";
                    cout << 2 << " ";
cout << 3 << " ";
```

Comment: Just so you know I'm new to programming just started learning this week. I can accept your quote " you're just seeing the "lower" stack frames complete their processing", however, I still don't really get it. It's printing something the same number of times as the original value as if it's in a loop but it's not.

Comment: Why not just print it out once since that last cout is only called once?

Comment: @UniverseX You'd have to ask the person who wrote it!

Comment: No there code is fine. I don't mean that literally to display only once. That's easy, just comment out that last cout line. I meant I'm still trying to understand how the stack frame, as you called it, is displaying those last numbers on it's own with only one cout call.

Comment: @UniverseX One cout call -> one line of output, which is exactly what you're getting. I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the confusion at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this simpler case:

```
void foo(int x) {
     std::cout << x << '\n';
     bar(x-1);
     std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

I suppose you have no problem to predict the output of eg `foo(3)`:

```
3
... any output from bar(2) comes here ...
3
```

Now replace `bar` with `foo` and add a stop for the recursion and you have the same as `PrintTest`.

Answer (score 0):

To be what you expected, you may try pass-by-reference. All the changes to the passed `test` does reference to original `a`.

```
void PrintTest(int& test) // pass-by-reference
{ 
    if (test < 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << test << " ";
        test -= 1;                // decrease self 
        PrintTest(test);          // and pass reference
        cout << test << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: ya but it still prints 0 out to the console x amount of times. Why not just print it out once? Printing itself out x amount of times as if it's in a loop is then what still gets me. btw I'm a bit new to programming. Just going through the learning phase now.